# Why taskinfo syntax file does not work as expect?

Tags: vim

I have following syntax file:

```
syn match TaskName /^\[.*\]/
syn match TaskType  /^\[.*\]\s*\zs[a-z]*/
syn match TaskDescription  /^\[.*\]\s*[a-z]*\s\+\zs.*/
hi def link TaskName Title
hi def link TaskType Todo
hi def link TaskDescription Comment
```

and the context is:

```
Task          Type          Command
[file-run]    local         no description
```

why only `[file-run]` is matched?

If I type `/^\[.*\]\s*\zs[a-z]*` in normal mode, `local` will be matched.

Comment: This isn't off-topic for Stack Overflow, but you could post Vim questions on the [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com). The answerers there tend to have a broader and more complete knowledge of Vi/Vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is not matching is that `:syn match` does not try and
evaluate text it has already matched. So, it **cannot** match against the text already matched by `:syn match TaskName`.

---

Additionally, there's a lot that could be improved upon your patterns, notably:

- You have a lot of pattern atoms that will match the empty string.
  This makes pattern matching slow, as patterns like `[a-z]*` will match
  everywhere (this pattern in particular is even pointed out as an example of
  a pattern to avoid in the help documentation for `:syn-pattern`). In most
  cases it is better to match **1 or more** matches with `\+` than **0 or
  more** matches with `*`.
- You can make all of your patterns more brief and more clear using other
  arguments of `:syn match`.

---

I would suggest leveraging the power of the `nextgroup` argument in combination
with the `skipwhite` argument of `:syn match`:

- `nextgroup` allows you to tell
  Vim to try and match the groups specified after this match.
- The `skipwhite` argument allows you to skip over tabs and spaces when
  trying to match the next group with `nextgroup`.

---

Keeping these in mind, you could rewrite your patterns to look like:

```
syn match TaskName /^\[.\+\]/ nextgroup=TaskType skipwhite
syn match TaskType /[a-z]\+/ nextgroup=TaskDescription skipwhite
syn match TaskDescription /\w\+\(\s\+\w\+\)*/
```

In order to do this, I've also edited your `TaskDescription` match to be “a word,
followed by 0 or more words separated by whitespace".

You can see that utilizing `nextgroup` and `skipwhite` makes each syntax match
more brief, in addition to making the contents of each group more clear.

---

Relevant `:help` queries:

```
:h :syn-match
:h :syn-pattern
:h :syn-nextgroup
:h :syn-skipwhite
```